# Help me with XML and AS2

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

**Here is my XML that holds all images. I want the to get the childNodes of subcategory, sub1, sub2, sub3 etc...**

< allImages>

```
<images>
    <category>Architecture</category>
    <img>Arch_1.jpg</img>
    <subcategory>
        <sub>sub1</sub>
        <sub>sub2</sub>
        <sub>sub3</sub>
    </subcategory>
</images>
<images>
    <category>People</category>
    <img>People_1.jpg</img>
    <subcategory>
        <sub>sub4</sub>
        <sub>sub5</sub>
    </subcategory>
</images>
```

< /allImages>

**Here is the AS2 code**

function loadXML(loaded) {

> if (loaded) {
>
> > xmlNode= this.firstChild;
> >
> > galleries = [[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]]];
> >
> > category = [];
> >
> > total= xmlNode.childNodes.length;
> >
> > for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
> >
> > > > category[i] = xmlNode.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
> > > >
> > > > galleries = xmlNode.childNodes[i].childNodes[1].childNodes;
> > > >
> > > > trace(category[i]);
> > > >
> > > > trace(galleries);
> > > >
> > > > }
> >
> > } 
> >     else {
> >
> > > > trace("xml is not loaded!");
> >
> > }

}

xmlData = new XML();

xmlData.ignoreWhite = true;

xmlData.onLoad = loadXML;

xmlData.load("gallery.xml");

**The result looks like this**

Architecture

< sub>sub1< /sub>

< sub>sub2< /sub>

< sub>sub3< /sub>

People

< sub>sub4< /sub>

< sub>sub5< /sub>

Answer (score 0):

For sake of yourself and god use greensock xmlparser